# How to close internet explorer window on Windows CE 5.0

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, windows-mobile

Is there a way to close IE in Windows CE, I was try `window.close()`, `self.close()`, etc... and it did not work. I was searching long for the answer, but have found nothing, a last I am asking here for help, if anyone has come to this issue.

Comment: Hmm. If `window.close()` doesn't work, it could well be that it's not possible to do programmatically. What do you need this for?

Comment: I am developing a mobile asp application which needs as much screen as there is, so the IE will run in full screen mode, and it would be very handy if there could be a link which would logout of the app and closed the IE.